# How to get the URL of a xmlhttp request (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, http-headers

On [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)(url) there is an example of how to do an AJAX call with plain Javascript. If you look at the example you will see the call is triggered by a button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

This is the function:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

What I would like to do is get the URL of the outgoing AJAX call which is [ajax_info.txt](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_info.txt)(url):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
```

Im trying to put that URL in to an alert, so I tried calling the headers of the response using `getAllResponseHeaders()` hoping that it will give me the `Host` like so:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders());
```

It does give me all the headers but not the Host. So my next move was trying to set the Host myself using `setRequestHeader()` but then I realized the Header needs a Value which I had to send myself, so this will not work. What else can I try to get/fetch the outgoing AJAX URL in the alert?

Please note the code is just an example and I know that changing headers(in this case) is prohibited because of Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: [Standard warning here about w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: I know they are not the best, Im just using them as an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how much access you have to the code but you can over-ride `XMLHttpRequest.open` and hook the url there.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (function(open) {
  return function(method,url,async) {
      console.log('the outgoing url is ',url);
      open.apply(this,arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eUz7p/).

Comment: In my project I don't know the outgoing URL, if I knew I wouldn't have to fetch it...

Comment: @Youss, how are you passing the outgoing `URL` to the `XMLHTTPRequest` object?

Comment: Im not passing anything, Im scraping websites which make AJAX calls. So I need to get these outgoing URL's

Comment: @Youss, I made an edit, may/may not suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort:) I don't know if this will work for "all AJAX calls" but at the least its a very good starting point.