# Infer request method while intercepting AJAX responses

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm intercepting, *globally*, for lack of a better word, all AJAX responses - Are there any elegant ways to determine what was the method (`POST/PUT/GET` etc) that was originally used to perform the request that triggered the intercepted response?

Here's what I do to perform the intercepts:

```
(function() {
  var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener('load', function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        // what was the method used in the *original* request?
      }
    });

    origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add a comment or mark this quest as a dup, not having enough reps, but I beleave this has been answered here: [Ajax / XMLHttpRequest tracking using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144203/ajax-xmlhttprequest-tracking-using-javascript)

Comment: I don't see how that's similar - the answer you posted simply hijacks an AJAX call - I similarly, yes, intercept them but just the `response`, not `send` - the question is how to track the original callee that triggered that `response` I'm intercepting.

Comment: In that answer the OP also leaves a comment to another answer where `open` is overriden with a function that fetches the `url` and the `method` you're after, is also passed there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750158/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-xmlhttp-request-ajax/20750355#20750355