# Redirecting XMLHTTP request - Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a web page that has a too much content and javascript. When the page loads it makes multiple requests using Ajax and XMLHttp to load data. Is there a way to hook up all these requests and direct them to a different server.

For example the webpage fetches data from **www.apple.com/data** and **www.mango.com/data** after it is loaded. Is is possible to insert a script somewhere in the webpage which automatically changes any request made to **www.orange.com/data**.

Waiting for answer. Thanks

Comment: a simple solution, declare one glocal `var apis = ['apple.com/data', 'mango.com/data']`, then after succeeds to fetch data from above, change `apis = ['orange.com/data']`, your ajax call will be like ajax(apis)

Comment: If you use jquery, you can add a global handler to the ajaxSend event, add you own logic in the handler and do ajax.abort() to the requests you don't want to be sent.
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/

Comment: @Sphink - that is a possibility, however the issue is that the webpage consists of too many urls and they are dynamic. They change depending on the type of content being displayed. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @AnthonyC - the thing is that  these requests are not supposed to be aborted but redirected to a different server. If I abort the request using  ajaxSend event handler will it be possible to invoke the same function to request from a different server?

Comment: understood, i use abort just an example. It can be abort or redirect to another uri or even have the payload modified. I can give more detail in the answer if you allow jQuery to be loaded (or if it is already loaded).

Comment: @AnthonyC - I already have Jquery loaded. Waiting for your answer :)

Comment: @AnthonyC - i will be waiting for your answer. Even if it does not solve the problem, it will take me a step further. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a global handler to the ajaxSend event, the event will be triggered right before the ajax request being sent out. So you can check the request uri, apply some filtering logic, and then redirect the request by abort the original and resend it.
Below is an example

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, opt) {
    if (opt.url.indexOf("www.apple.com") !== -1) {
        // abort the request
        xhr.abort();
        // change the uri to www.orange.com
        opt.url = opt.url.replace("www.apple.com", "www.orange.com");
        $.ajax(opt);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I followed Anthony C's answer and it did actually work. But the problem with his solution is that it only works with Ajax requests not XMLHttpRequests (I am not sure why, I am a beginner at this topic.) However digging on his idea of creating a hook I came across a similar post here [How to get the URL of a xmlhttp request (AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750158/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-xmlhttp-request-ajax). The code provided a way to fetch the requested URL for each request. So by a little tweak to the code I managed to come up with this:-

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (function(open) {
  return function(method,url,async) {
      var uri=getLocation(url);// use get location function to convert requested url string into readable url 
      if(uri.hostname!="orange.com"){
          url="https://orange.com" + url;
      }
      open.apply(this,arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);

var getLocation = function(href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l;
};
```

This code at top of the page allows me to change the host name of all XMLHttpRequests that are not directed towards orange.com. Though I am sure there are better ways to write this code as well but since I am not an expert over javascript this will suffice my need for the time.